# c# Autoproperties and Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, automatic-properties

I have a base case that gets derived so i have few int and string Auto properties

```
// base class 

   public virtual int MyVariable {get; set; }; 


// Derived class
    private int myVariable = 0;
    public override int MyVariable 
    {
        get { return myVariable ; }
        set { myVariable = value; }

    }
```

How can i do the same with a Dictionary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty much the same, though you will of course need to change the type from `int` to your dictionary type.

Example with a `Dictionary<string,int>`:

Base class:

```
public virtual Dictionary<string,int> MyVariable {get; set; };
```

Derived class:

```
private Dictionary<string,int> myVariable = new Dictionary<string,int>();
public override Dictionary<string,int> MyVariable 
{
    get { return myVariable ; }
    set { myVariable = value; }

}
```